# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: Unable to find chromedriver. Please download the server from

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, selenium-chromedriver, ruby-2.4

using ruby 2.4.0p0 , Rails 5.2.3

Got error while running system test cases for rails application:

```
Error:
SubscriptionsTest#test_visit_susbcription:
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: Unable to find chromedriver. Please download the server from
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH.
More info at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver.
```

My system test is as:

```
require "application_system_test_case"

    class SubscriptionsTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
      test "visit susbcription" do
        visit subscriptions_url
      end
    end
```

please suggestthe possible way out. 
Command to run system  test:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails test -v test/system/subscriptions_test.rb
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this issue can be resolved by adding below gem in gemfile.

```
gem 'webdrivers', '~> 4.0'
```